# MSSQL: INSERT record while using 2 select statements

Tags: select, insert

For the initial population of a MSSQL database, I need to add all Roles to all Users through a script.

So basically this is what I had in mind, but of course the VALUES part needs to be implemented correctly.

Table User
1 John
2 Will
3 Kate

Table Role
1 Can view dashboard
2 Can view reports
3 Can edit data

Table UserRole, PK (and FKs) UserId and RoleId

- 1, 1
- 1, 2
- 1, 3
- 2, 1
- 2, 2
- 2, 3
- 3, 1
- 3, 2
- 3, 3

INSERT INTO UserRole (UserId, RoleId) VALUES (User.Id, Role.Id)

Who knows how to do this?

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. Is this MySQL? What do you mean "while using 2 select"?

Comment: I've edited my original post. Hopefully this clarifies it a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
create table [User] (ID int identity(1,1),Name varchar(20))

create table [Role] (ID int identity(1,1),RoleName varchar(50))

create table [UserRole] (UserId int, RoleId int)

insert into [User] (Name) values ('John')
insert into [user] (Name) values ('Will')
insert into [User] (Name) values ('Kate')

insert into Role (RoleName) VALUES ('Can view dashboard')
insert into Role (RoleName) VALUES ('Can view reports')
insert into Role (RoleName) VALUES ('Can edit date')


INSERT INTO [UserRole] (UserId, RoleID)
select U.ID,R.ID from [User] U,[Role] R

select * from UserRole
ORDER BY UserID,RoleId
```

Should give you the output you expect